# Scroll horizontal listview when items are inside screen(not visible)

Tags: flutter, listview, scroll

I have pageview builder and a horizontal listview in my screen. Both are populated with same image list. On page change of pageview i want listview to be scrolled only if items are inside the screen(not visible). heres my onchange code in pageview:

```
onPageChanged: (int index) { if(_scrollController.position.atEdge) { _scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent - index * 44.0);}}
```

I am popluating pageview.builder n listview.separated in reverse, so last item of list is visible on screen at first. heres my listview code:

```
ListView.separated(
separatorBuilder: (context, builder) {
  return SizedBox(
    width: 2.w,
  );
},
itemCount: imagesByCameraIdInter.images!.length,
key: _listViewKey,
shrinkWrap: true,
physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
controller: _scrollController,
itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
  // _scrollDown();
  final reversedIndex =
      imagesByCameraIdInter.images!.length - 1 - index;

  return InkWell(
    onTap: () {
      ref.read(currentImageProvider.notifier).setCurrentImage(image);
    },
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.w, vertical: 4.h),
      child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.r),
                border: currentImage.id ==
                        imagesByCameraIdInter.images![reversedIndex].id!
                    ? Border.all(
                        color: Helper.primary,
                        width: 2.w,
                      )
                    : Border.all(width: 2.w, color: Colors.transparent),
              ),
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.r),
                  border: currentImage.id ==
                          imagesByCameraIdInter
                              .images![reversedIndex].id!
                      ? Border.all(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          width: 0.7.w,
                        )
                      : Border.all(
                          width: 0.6.w, color: Colors.transparent),
                ),
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.r),
                  child: Image.network(
                    imagesByCameraIdInter
                        .images![reversedIndex].urlThumb!,
                    gaplessPlayback: true,
                    width: 44.w,
                    height: 44.h,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    errorBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                        Object exception, StackTrace? stackTrace) {
                      return ClipRRect(
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'assets/images/error_image.jpeg',
                          width: 44.w,
                          height: 44.h,
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
    ),
  );
}),),
```

[image]

i want scroll on horizontal listview when my pageview slide is changed lets say 7 times(there are 7 items of horizontal listview visible so i want it to scroll after that) and then i slide to 8 then horizontal list will scroll to left by some pixels(lets say offset of 44 which is the width of item). How can i achieve it?

Comment: Do you know "Scrollable.ensureVisible" ?